# Libre Office Mac - where can I find a list of shortcuts?

Tags: libreoffice

This is specifically for the Writer, but if you want to add Spreadsheets too, I don't mind.

I am trying to do things like indent/unindent from the keyboard.  Couldn't find (very quick look) in the menu, so no shortcuts from there.

I've looked at [Shortcut Keys for LibreOffice Writer](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer) which doesn't seem to care too much about Macs (no Apple command button mentions), but I have also noticed that

I have also looked at Tools, Customize, Keyboard and I guess I could figure it out and customize it from there.  This question is just asking if there is a cheatsheet that I can look at somewhere already with Mac specifics.

p.s. the linked doc page says that Ctrl+A does **select all**.  And I can do that with ⌘+A.  Does that mean any CTRL on that doc means ⌘ on Apple?

Comment: Generally speaking yes, substitute ⌘ for Ctrl for use on a Mac, however not all shortcuts listed in the linked document may work on a Mac.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much what I figured.  Thanks for confirmation.  If you care, write it up as an answer and I'll accept it if no one points to a cheatsheet somewhere (I'll wait for a few days first though).